# Text alignment next to af figure

Tags: positioning, text, alignment

I am trying to position a figure with a text aligned. Basically, I am trying to get the figure with the text shown below. This is supposed to be positioned top right corner of the page.

So far I have this:

```latex
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
        \textsc{\large Technical University of Denmark}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Images/DTU}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
```

I hope you can help me here.

[image: o]

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your MWE, I have the following proposal.

## Output

[image]

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphbox}


\begin{document}
\hfill{\scshape\large Technical University of Denmark}%
\hskip1em
\includegraphics[align=t,vshift=.6em,width=0.2\textwidth]{DTU}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Approved all the proposals. Very good.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

(size of image you can adjust with width of `p{<width>}` column type, see suggested code below)

For this image you should have in your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

I guess, that this image you like to have in header in the first  (or all) page(s). In this case, you should integrate in document header definition (using `fancyheader`?) the following code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft}X p{22mm}}
    \large\textsc{Technical University of Denmark}
&
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{example-image-duck}
\end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways without any special package such as `graphbox`, `adjustbox` or even `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\hfill{\scshape Technical University of Denmark}%
\hskip1em
\vtop{%
  \vskip-1em
  \hbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{DTU}%
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks - it works